# Directory for using colorbrewer schemes in combination with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, color

I am using Windows 8.1 (64 bit version), TexnicCenter version 2.02 to compile my LaTeX files via pdflatex. I am using pgfplots because of it's very nice possibilities in visualize scientific data but since the default colors of line plots are a bit restricted, I started using Colorbrewer schemes. That all worked great at different PCs and everything is fine but now I try to compile the same files at a new notebook (system information given above) and some "new" error messages came up:

By using this example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}   
        \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[colorbrewer cycle list=Dark2]

    \addplot {rnd};
    \addplot {rnd-1};
    \addplot {rnd-2};
    \addplot {rnd-3};
    \addplot {rnd-4};
    \addplot {rnd-5};
    \addplot {rnd-6};
    \addplot {rnd-7};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

...I get the following errors:

```
    ! I can't find file 'pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex'.
    <to be read again>
    \relax
    > 1.3 \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
    > Please type another input file name
```

At other systems there were no need to put the file 'pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex' anywhere, because "LaTeX did not ask for it". I started searching for a file named like that and found it here (https://github.com/vtraag/tikz-colorbrewer). I then tried to put the file somewhere, I thought LaTeX would find it, but equal to which directory I copied the file, the error messages came up over and over again.

Here are now my 2 little questions:

1.) Why is LaTeX looking for that file? In my opinion, I contains the same information (or even less) than the 'tikzlibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex'-file I am successfully using (in the direction: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgfplots\libs).

2.) Which direction would you propose to make this all work? Maybe you have some idea, how to get the problem done.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please go to http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzlibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex download the file and save it (with the exact name it has) in your current directory and compile your document. Doest it work now?

Comment: I just copied the file into the working directory and it worked fine.

Comment: Great! I think then that this answer can be closed, since it was a problem that was solved by downloading the right file. For installation of personal packages on MikTeX, please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a problem that was solved by downloading the right file.